# How can I test if a line is intersecting with an arbitrary amount of other, unknown lines in python?

Tags: python, geometry, lines

I want to test if a point is inside a polygon, and to do that I am using the [ray-casting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Ray_casting_algorithm), where I send a line from the point to the origin of the screen and test how many intersections it makes (if it makes an odd number of intersections then the point is inside a polygon, otherwise it's outside). The problem is in calculating whether or not the ray intersects. Is the only way of calculating intersections through knowing the start and end coordinates of every line segment onscreen and calculating intersections with those lines? Or is there another method (regardless of it's complexity)?

If this is the only way of finding intersections of lines, then what would be the fastest way of calculating intersections?

At times there may be around 500 lines onscreen, all of which would need to be checked for collisions. How taxing on one's system would an algorithm be to test collisions with all of those lines in real time?

Comment: [This article](http://alienryderflex.com/intersect) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) package. The [manual](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) documents a method called **contains()** (scroll down to section 'Binary predicates') which seems to fit your needs.

As for performance considerations see the manual sections: 'Performance' and 'Prepared geometries'.

Comment: I'm a student of python and while I know about the Shapely package I want to see if I can do this without it as a learning experience.

Comment: Then you are looking at the field of computational geometry. See this: http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/ , there's a pdf on the algorithms with pseudocode, it's a bit cryptic though :).

Comment: Awesome, that's a fantastic introduction to what I've been wanting to learn! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

> then what would be the fastest way of calculating intersections?

You need to start with [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/565282/415628). That describes a common and fast way of testing for intersection of line segments in the 2D case using the vector cross-product.

To use the method above you'll need to represents the lines in point plus vector form. For the ray you'll need to start from the point of interest **p** and the vector will be direction towards the origin, which is just -**p** (minus **p**).

> ray: **p** - *s***p** (*s* >= 0)

If the line segment endpoints are **a** and **b** then just take the point **a** and use as the vector the direction from **a** to **b** (this is **b** - **a**, lets call it  **w**).

> **w** = **b** - **a**
> line segment: **a** + *t***w** (0 <= *t* <= 1)

[image: Scenarios for the intersection test]

Now use the above method:

> **p** - *s***p** = **a** + *t***w**
> (**p** - *s***p**) × -**p** = (**a** + *t***w**) × -**p** --- cross both sides by -**p**
> 0 = - **a** × **p** - *t***w** × **p** --- since a vector crossed with itself is zero (**p** × **p** = 0)
>
> *t* = **p** × **a** / **w** × **p** --- solving for *t* (remember **a** × **b** = -(**b** × **a**))

Here we can do our first two tests:

1. If **w** × **p** = 0, the ray and line are parallel (or collinear) so they never intersect (or intersect at all points if collinear), so we can exit the test early (scenario 3).
2. If *t* < 0 or *t* > 1 the intersection point is outside the line segment between **a** and **b** (scenario 2).

Continue using the cross product method to solve for *s*

> *s* = (**a** - **p**) × **w** / **w** × **p**

Now our last check: if *s* < 0 the intersection happens 'behind' the point **p** (away from the origin, scenario 4) so doesn't add to your ray-casting count.

---

The challenge remains to calculate this quickly in python, and I would say that the best approach is to try to vectorise those 500 checks into larger matrix operations and implement that using numpy.

Comment: I would be very surprised if 500 checks took a significant amount of time. Vectorizing it would be much much faster, of course, but if the OP just wants "interactive-rate" performance I think the easy way would be sufficient.

Comment: I second that, avoid premature optimization.